# Using QEMU as a runtime/compatibility layer (basic host OS)

Tags: linux, qemu, host

I am using a QEMU VM as my main OS.
But still, I have a Lubuntu machine that is serving as a host but technically is unecessary.
As well, I need to sign into the host machine at first and it is running some services like a window manager, networking etc. which is only consuming RAM despite being useless cause of PCIe Passthrough.
So why not running the VM bare metal? I like that I don't have to care about native hardware problems that would occur.

So I was wondering if there was some kind of pure "QEMU OS" that is serving as a compatibility layer between the VM and the hardware?
Maybe a pure linux kernel that is starting a X server and QEMU but nothing more...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could certainly construct such a Linux, although I wouldn't expect it to be straightforward. And X without even a window manager can be rather ungainly. But... I'm not sure this is the kind of question that gets much traction on SO -- it's not really about programming, is it?

Comment: QEMU+KVM are not really designed to work that way. If you want a hypervisor whose design is "there is no full-blown OS underneath the VMs" you might look at Xen...

Comment: Thank you, this is what I searched for.